# Illegal class file: Class module-info is missing a super type. Class file version 53

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, firebase-performance

When I add firebase perf dependency into my project i am getting this error `Illegal class file: Class module-info is missing a super type. Class file version 53.`
My Gradle and google services project-level dependencies are

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
```

and I followed the exact steps mentioned in their docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android.

I have tried clean and rebuild and clearing the Android Studio cache.

And also tried similarly issue resolution from StackOverflow

Project level build gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'  // Performance Monitoring plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

App level build gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
// Apply the Performance Monitoring plugin to enable instrumentation
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }

}
dependencies {
// Not added all dependencies , Just the firebase one SINCE ITS PRETTY LONG
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Add your `build.gradle` to the question.

Comment: try removing fabric and test it with performance only , maybe its a library conflict.?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441409/android-studio-project-not-compiling-after-updating-firebase-perf-plugin-class/59015733

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Adding this to your app-level `build.gradle` file solves the problem temporarily

```
debug {
          FirebasePerformance {
            // Set this flag to 'false' to disable @AddTrace annotation processing and
            // automatic HTTP/S network request monitoring
            // for a specific build variant at compile time.
            instrumentationEnabled false
          }
        }
```

EDIT as per other answers and comments

Change the gradle plugin to `3.6.0` to resolve it as it has been fixed in that version

Comment: This solves my problem, thanks.
I think, someone should report this to the bug tracker.

Comment: Worked for me. I searched for 2 days for this solution.

Comment: Siddhivinayak After using the above code does the Perfomance API work?

Comment: @kubs Nope it's disabling the Performance so that the build can proceed further. So this is a temporary solution to get your build working but you can try with an old version of the library or the plugin if available to make it work. Hopefully, that helps!

Comment: @Siddhivinayak clarification the api works on runtime?

Comment: @kubs No, It doesn't

Comment: I can confirm that upgrading your gradle plugin to 3.6.0 is a permanent fix, should edit this answer to stop people from adding in this hack.

Answer (score 6):

FYI, this was an AGP bug...it's been fixed in AGP 3.6

Comment: What is agp and do you have a source for whatever you're saying? I'm looking for a solution but I don't know what you're suggesting

Comment: @NickCardoso Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) and kenyee is suggesting that it's been fixed in the version 3.6

Answer (score 3):

On updating build Gradle from 3.5.1 to 3.6.0 fixed my issue.

Comment: 3.6.0 is still in alpha wondering if anyone has a fix that does not involve using an alpha version

Answer (score 1):

Also **remove this** from `gradle.properties` if you happen to have it there for any reason:

```
android.enableR8=false
```

(I got the error even with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2` if the above line was present)