# Android studio project not compiling after updating firebase-perf plugin (Class module-info is missing)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gson, firebase-performance

everyone. I'm using gradle version 5.6.2. I updated my android studio project dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    classpath "com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1"
}
```

I apply the plugins like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But now when I compile my project this error shows up:

```
Illegal class file: Class module-info is missing a super type. Class file version 53. (Java 9)
```

It says the problem is in app\build\intermediates\transforms\FirebasePerformancePlugin\bus\debug\9\module-info.class

Inside there's this:

```
module com.google.gson {
    requires transitive java.sql;

    exports com.google.gson;
    exports com.google.gson.annotations;
    exports com.google.gson.reflect;
    exports com.google.gson.stream;
}
```

My guess is that firebase started using Java 9 but my project is currently working with Java 8. I tried changing the version to 9 but I get this error:

```
Could not target platform: 'Java SE 9' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.
```

Answer (score 5):

This is [a bug in the Android Gradle plugin](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140290149), fixed now in [Android Studio 3.6](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview).  It looks to only be an issue on Windows, as the path format uses the backslash `\` instead of forward slash `/`. I confirmed I am able to build my app on Android Studio 3.5 on Linux, but not Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It was solved temporarily by adding this to build.gradle :

```
debug {
          FirebasePerformance {
            // Set this flag to 'false' to disable @AddTrace annotation processing and
            // automatic HTTP/S network request monitoring
            // for a specific build variant at compile time.
            instrumentationEnabled false
          }
        }
```