# Illegal class file: Class module-info is missing a super type. com.google.code.gson\gson\2.8.6

Tags: android

I am trying to run my app on android studio but am getting this error

Illegal class file: Class module-info is missing a super type.

Message{kind=ERROR, text=Illegal class file: Class module-info is missing a super type., sources=[C:\Users\Toshiba.DESKTOP-GDLU8MO.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.gson\gson\2.8.6\9180733b7df8542621dc12e21e87557e8c99b8cb\gson-2.8.6.jar], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.system2.tranxav"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = [
                'src/main/res/layouts/drawer',
                'src/main/res',
                'src/main/res/layouts',
        ]
    }
}
}

  dependencies {

implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.1'
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-java:1.47.0'
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'co.paystack.android:paystack:3.0.10'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:1.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.16.5'
implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0'
implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.NaikSoftware:StompProtocolAndroid:1.1.5'
implementation 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.Flutterwave.rave-android:rave_android:2.1.6'


annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

}

my gradle version is 4.4 How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

1.Used Android Gradle plugin v3.6.0+ and Gradle v5.6.4+.
[Android studio project not compiling after updating firebase-perf plugin (Class module-info is missing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441409/android-studio-project-not-compiling-after-updating-firebase-perf-plugin-class)

2.Or going back to gson 2.8.5
https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1625