# java.lang.SecurityException in android.os.Parcel.readException

Tags: java, android

We are struggling with this issue since months and never

**java.lang.SecurityException in android.os.Parcel.readException**

We tried various solutions found here on StackOverflow, but any of those solved our issue.
We know that is a common problem, but the lack of a real solution is a problem.

Has anyone a possible approach to solve this everywhere?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:365)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:383)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:252)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:271)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:784)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1954)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1900)
  at android.app.job.IJobCallback$Stub$Proxy.completeWork (IJobCallback.java:218)
  at android.app.job.JobParameters.completeWork (JobParameters.java:220)
  at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl$WrapperWorkItem.complete (JobIntentService.java:268)
  at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground (JobIntentService.java:394)
  at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground (JobIntentService.java:383)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:345)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:784)
```

this is less frequent, but we also have it

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1608)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1555)
  at android.app.job.IJobCallback$Stub$Proxy.jobFinished (IJobCallback.java:167)
  at android.app.job.JobService$JobHandler.handleMessage (JobService.java:147)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:150)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5621)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:794)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

Gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        google()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url 'https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur/raw/master/releases/' }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK" }
    google()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId '****************'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 32310206
        versionName '4.3.2'

        //impostare all'api level minimo supportato
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.code.gson/gson/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.code.gson/gson/pom.xml'
        exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("/Library/AndroidKeys/******.keystore")
            storePassword '********'
            keyAlias "**********"
            keyPassword '*************'
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            versionNameSuffix " debug"

            FirebasePerformance {
                //MOMENTANEAMENTE INSERISCO QUESTA OPZIONE PER OVVIARE ALL'ERRORE
                //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369285/illegal-class-file-class-module-info-is-missing-a-super-type-class-file-versio
                // Set this flag to 'false' to disable @AddTrace annotation processing and
                // automatic HTTP/S network request monitoring
                // for a specific build variant at compile time.
                instrumentationEnabled false
            }
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->

        //Aggiungo nelle stringhe nome e codice versione
        variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
        variant.resValue "string", "versionCode", "$variant.versionCode"
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def newName = output.outputFile.name
            newName = newName.replace("-release", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "vc" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            newName = newName.replace("-debug", "-DEBUG-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "vc" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            output.outputFileName = "${newName}"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    implementation 'com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3:interactivemedia:3.17.0'

    implementation 'org.prebid:prebid-mobile-sdk:1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.0'
    //GOOGLE
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    //JetPack
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.10.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.6@aar'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    api 'com.outbrain.obsdk:obsdk:3.7.10'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:1.4.0'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.5'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:6.1.5'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.6.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: share the code, highlighting the lines where the errors are

Comment: I see this type of error too. Reading the traces - nothing in the stacktrace points back to any line of code outside of core anrdroid & java components or gives a clue what would be causing it. Can you share the app build.gradle file? Maybe there's a common library.

Comment: please provide more information on the context. Which action or situation produces this error? I guess that the java.lang.NullPointerException is a different problem, please focus just on the first one

Comment: Added the gradle file.
I cannot add any specific part of the code cause it's not in a specific part that the error is triggered.

Comment: Any feedback here?

Comment: Sorry, no ideas. Only non-standard library I see in common with mine is MPAndroidChart. Of course it could be coming from that, or any of the other common ones like firebase, play-services, etc...